# JS addEventListener -> update data-action

Tags: javascript, html

I have a game where you press a button, depending on what you press it shows up a menu by using data-action. E.g I got a main menu, press "news" and the news menu will be called using data-action="news".

Now I will return data via the game, and will therefore send that data (not relevant) over via JS using addEventListener. However, I'd like to make an if-statement which will set the data-action to whatever was sent from the game. How to update data-action via JS?

If event.date.type is "news" -> show the new-news menu which will be shown by setting data-action to "new-news". This doesn't work, how to do it?

```
if (event.data.type == "news"){
    data-action="new-news"
}
```

Comment: Show all the code including the markup and `addEventListener` you describe, give is the complete reproducible code

Answer (score 1):

Use the [dataset interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```
element.dataset.action = 'new-news'
```

Comment: I see no "element" in the OP  code, but I get where your assumption is made here.  Also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you are having trouble assigning a data element to some element. It seems to be just a syntax error.

Instead of:

```
data-action = "new-news"
```

Use the *dataset* like following:

```
element.dataset.action = "new-news"
```

This should work :)